# Russian law of extradition

Tags: extradition, russia

If a Russian hacker hacks a computer system in India, can India seek Interpol's help to get that hacker extradited to India?

I mean, does Russia allow extradition of Russian nationals to other countries like India, Pakistan, or Sri Lanka?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Russian Constitution [Article 61(1)](http://www.departments.bucknell.edu/russian/const/ch2.html) prohibits this, stating "The citizen of the Russian Federation may not be deported out of Russia or extradited to another state".

Comment: How can a country like India apprehend that hacker?

Comment: Well, if the person is outside of Russia and is taken into custody... When he is in-country, unless Russia prosecutes him for violating Russian law, there is no legal recourse.